# Why is the axes for the .mean() method in pandas the opposite in this scenario?

Tags: python, pandas, mean, axis

I have a dataframe, `height_df`, with three measurements, `'height_1','height_2','height_3'`. I want to create a new column that has the mean of all three heights. A printout of `height_df` is given below

```
    height_1  height_2  height_3
0       1.78      1.80      1.80
1       1.70      1.70      1.69
2       1.74      1.75      1.73
3       1.66      1.68      1.67
```

The following code works but I don't understand why

```
height_df['height'] = height_df[['height_1','height_2','height_3']].mean(axis=1)
```

I actually want the mean across the row axes, i.e. for each row compute the average of the three heights. I would have thought then that the axis argument in mean should be set to 0, as this is what corresponds to applying the mean across rows, however axis=1 is what gets the result I am looking for. Why is this? If `axis=1` is for columns and `axis=0` is for rows then why does `.mean(axis=1)` take the mean across rows?

Comment: Think it's `apply(np.mean, axis=1)`, where the function is applied along axis=1. `df.mean(axis='columns')` so you don't get confused :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to tell mean to work across columns with `axis=1`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"height_1":[1.78,1.7,1.74,1.66],"height_2":[1.8,1.7,1.75,1.68],"height_3":[1.8,1.69,1.73,1.67]})
df = df.assign(height_mean=df.mean(axis=1))
df = df.assign(height_mean=df.loc[:,['height_1','height_2','height_3']].mean(axis=1))
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 height_1  height_2  height_3  height_mean
     1.78      1.80      1.80     1.793333
     1.70      1.70      1.69     1.696667
     1.74      1.75      1.73     1.740000
     1.66      1.68      1.67     1.670000
```